# how to convert array get from result_array to normal array

Tags: php, codeigniter

by using result_array i got array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [toid] => 34 ) [1] => Array ( [toid] => 37 ) )
```

but,i want normal array, as i need to pass that to query.

Comment: In which you want your result data. can you please put sample?

Comment: show your expected output

Comment: show your database query also

Comment: that is a normal array

Comment: define a "normal array" to me this *is* a normal array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Old Array       
$Old_Array = array(
    array(
        "toid" => 34
    ),
    array(
        "toid" => 37
    )
);
//Output => Array ( [0] => Array ( [toid] => 34 ) [1] => Array ( [toid] => 37 ) ) 

//Converting to a normal New Array

$New_Array = array();
foreach ( $Old_Array as $Items ) 
    $New_Array[] = $Items["toid"];

//Output => Array ( [0] => 34 [1] => 37 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the multidimensional to simple array by using `array_column`

```
$arr = .... //Your not so normal array here

$normalArr = array_column($arr, 'toid');

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $normalArr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 34
    [1] => 37
)
```

Doc: [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: Is a nice answer, but we need to recall that this function is not working with a very old php versions, just working in PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7

Comment: Well you are assuming the OPs PHP version is older. :)